# Eclipse auto-import not working anymore

Tags: java, eclipse, import, libgdx, eclipse-neon

I use Eclipse Neon (on Mac OS) and work primarily with libgdx right now.
When I need to import some classes I do the <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> routine normally.

A non-libgdx class is imported fine, a libgdx class is only imported when I do it manually, so the build path is correct. Why does the "organize import"-command (applied by the key routine above) ignore libgdx?

I tried following steps:

- cleaning projects + restarting Eclipse
- restart computer
- refreshing gradle
- re-installing the same version of Eclipse
- installing an older version (Eclipse Mars)

Those steps don't solve the problem, maybe you have an idea?

Comment: What programming language is this?

Comment: Java, The problem is solved. I don't know exactly why, but I had to remove all projects and add them again. Maybe because I create a new repository and copy/paste all projects (in the file system) without updating the projects showed in Eclipse.